# How do I switch between different configurations in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

I have a GWT project running in dev and production mode as well as on web and mobile.

I have different web.xml files for each mode.

I also need different constants for each version. Currently I use this:

```
class Params {

   public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "value";
   ...
}
```

The value of SOME_CONSTANT may change across modes (versions of the app).

**How can I have different constants for each mode (dev, prod, web, mobile)?**

Answer (score 0):

> Move these constants into properties file one for each environment.

create a folder like this (It must be outside of your final generated war file, somewhere on server)

```
resources
 |__dev
 |__prod
 |__web
 |__mobile
```

Each folder contains properties file having values based on environment.

Pass the value of environment at start up of server as system property or environment variable. Load all the properties at the application context initialization and use it anywhere in your application.

Use **ServletContextListener** to read all the properties at server start up.

> How to load properties file based on system properties or environment variable?

Use

```
 System.getProperty()
```

or

```
System.getenv()
```

to read the location of properties file.

and load the properties file

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePath)));
```

You can store properties as Application context attribute that can be read from anywhere including JSP as well.

---

--EDIT--

Load properties file at server start-up:

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.x.y.z.server.AppServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

AppServletContextListener.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static Properties properties = new Properties();

    static {
        // load properties file
        String absolutePath = null;
        if (System.getenv("properties_absolute_path") == null) {
            absolutePath = System.getProperty("properties_absolute_path");
        } else {
            absolutePath = System.getenv("properties_absolute_path");
        }
        try {
            File file = new File(absolutePath);
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("properties", properties);
    }

    public static Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this on the GWT client side? Could you please give a more detailed example?

Comment: resources folder must be outside of your final generated war. place resources folder somewhere on server. Load properties file at server start up using servlet context listener. Pass the loaded properties file at the client side using simple RPC calls that is called from Entry Point class. You can do one more thing. store the properties as application scoped attribute that can be read in from anywhere including JSP also.

Comment: Could you please update your description and provide a more detailed example? How would you do it if there is no server in case of a PhoneGap environment?

Comment: What do you mean by that: "You can do one more thing. store the properties as application scoped attribute that can be read in from anywhere including JSP also" Could you give an example?

Comment: Do you know about `application scope` in a web application? I have updated my post to make more clear for you.

Comment: Does your solution also works in a PhoneGap environment?